# How to show Primary Contact Information in Account Form in Microsoft Dynamic CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, entities

In Microsoft Dynamic CRM, the Primary Contact is only showing as a Lookup field in the Account Form. But my boss want to show others information of Primary Contact such as: Name, Phone, Email, JobTitle in the Account Form.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

there is no customization that allows you to do that, you will have to program this functionality.

Using a plugin would be the easiest. You will have to make sure, that this plugin fires, either when updating the primary contact, or when one of these fields in the primary contact are updated.

So make sure to register plugins on create and update messages of the account and update of the contact.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamics CRM, there is a concept of a Quick view form. We can show the information of lookup control entity into this Quick view form. We can add the quick view form in a customization section where we are adding the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a Quick view form on **Contact** entity, just drop there all the fields that you want to show. Second step is to include this Quick View on the **Account** Form where you want to show it. Explained here:https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/adammurchison/2017/09/14/how-to-add-a-quick-view-form-in-microsoft-dynamics-365